# Split to multiple lines in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a dataset including the 3 years data from Google Analytics, I have a hard time to split the date into 3 different lines to display on Spotfire like the following pic.

[image]

Comment: Is the dataset split in any way? Or partitioned into equal parts representing the three years?

Comment: @PhilipCorneliusGlover I dont think so, the data set includs the daily records from 2015-2017. For everyday data, it has different number of records

Comment: Actually I figured out the multiple line part, just use `line by` on `Year`, now I have new issue, which is how to format the date on x-axis like in the picture

Comment: I would suggest creating an array of your dates, and setting that array as the x-axis.

Comment: The dataset is huge, and I dont think it is doable :( I guess it is just formatting problem, but I have no idea how to fix it. I tried to look up the yaxis in properties, did not find anything useful

Comment: Ah I see. Well then I suggest using [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com) as it is (to me) much easier to navigate and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your X axis is a date, making this a linear visualization. It seems like you are trying to compare years by month. In that case, keep the color by year option that you have currently, but change the X axis from your date column to `Month([DateColumn])`

Another option would be to [Trellis by year](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/vis/vis_trellis_visualizations.htm).

If you want to format the X as you have above, insert a calculated column and use this new column on the X axis:

```
Date(Year([DateColumn]),Month([DateColumn]),01) as [NewColumn]
```

This builds a date column based off the `YEAR` and `MONTH`from your `[DateColumn]` and forces the `DAY` part to `01`.

Comment: Actually I figured out the multiple line part, just use line by on Year, now I have new issue, which is how to format the date on x-axis like in the picture. Sorry maybe my question was not clear, the y-axis is total sessions and compare years by week.

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro see the updated answer for the formatted Y

Comment: Well, this is going to force the Month/1/Year part, but you can't expect the year 2017 data to be on the axis of a year which isn't 2017. That's why you'd either use `Month([DateColumn])` on the Y axis or Trellis by year. Your info-graphic doesn't make any sense doing it that way. How can year 2015 be associated with 4/1/2017 @AkiraKaneshiro?

Comment: Yes, I think it is just a text, X-axis doesn't means specific year. how can I change the text for x-axis. does it make sense?

Comment: It doesn't Akira. Can you, in your dataset, relate a row which has a Date in the year 2017 to something that isn't in 2017? Logically it doesn't make sense regardless of the datatype of the X axis. It's like I have a list of cars and their colors...[like this](https://pastebin.com/say6yYqD)... how could I graphically map a Civic to the color White? That's what you are trying to do it seems.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you uploaded a sample dataset--that could clarify why/how you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: I have another question, can I append the new data into the existing data in Spotfire?

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro usually you need to open a new question as this is completly different from the original one, but you can go to Insert  on the tool bar and select rows or columns depending on which you want to do.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks a lot :)